# Custom view (xib) not visible on storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xib, xcode-storyboard

I have a custom view `xib` where I have multiple `TableViews`. I am loading this inside a `ViewController` as a nested view:

```
ViewController
   |_ View
       |_ View (This is where I load my Custom View)
```

When I run my app, I can see the empty tables on screen, so my xib is loading correctly. 
So far so good.

My problem is, I am unable to see my tables in the storyboard. So I am not able to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+drag and proceed further.

How can I see my custom view inside the storyboard view?

Comment: You can't see xib views inside storyboard. You can use the file's owner to create IBOutlets and IBActions.

Comment: **DON'T FORGET @IBDesignable** !!!!

Comment: @FabioFelici , that's wrong.  Nowadays it is perfectly possible.  GentBerani gives the exact code.  Cheers!

Comment: @Fattie I think it wasn't possible when I commented, look at the date...

Comment: ciao, right @FabioFelici , notice I said "Nowadays ..."  !  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storyboards can only contain ViewControllers and Segues. If you want to access something in your xib from the ViewController to set the delegates etc., then you have to do it from code. You can't, for example, set the delegate of a `UITableView` from within IB when the target `ViewController` is in a Storyboard and the `UITableView` is in another xib.

Answer (score 6):

For example, we have **TopView** (my CustomView):

1. **TopView.xib**, set TopView class in **File's Owner**

   [image: TopView in Xcode]
2. **TopView.swift**

Note: Don't forget the @IBDesignable tag.

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable
class TopView: UIView {

    //MARK:- IB Outlets
    var contentView:UIView?

    //MARK:- Lifecycle
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupThisView()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupThisView()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setupThisView()
        contentView?.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    }

    //MARK:- Lifecycle methods
    private func setupThisView(){
        guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
        contentView = view
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
        let nibName = String(describing: TopView.self)
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self,options: nil).first as? UIView
    }
}
```

3.Add **UIView** in **Storyboard** and set the class of the view as **TopView**

[image: Custom class for UIView]

> If the **TopView** has **not** yet appeared in **Storyboard** then (this happens usually):

1. Enable **Editor -> Automatically Refresh Views**
2. Click on **Editor** -> **Refresh All Views**

> Still?

1. Clean the project: **⌘ + K**
2. Build the project **⌘ + B**

**Result in Storyboard:**
[image: Storyboard Result of TopView]