# Storyboard and xib do not show freshly added elements

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, xib

After updating to Xcode 8.1 our storyboards and xib are as usual. If we create a new xib/view/storyboard we can't see the freshly added elements in the new view.

Both of these are xib files. The left one is created befor the update, the right one after. You cant see the button eventhough that it is on top of everything and has contrains to fill the view. It also has text content and no sized classes.
[image]

I know that there are alot questions which explain that this could be sized classes.

[why storyboard ui elements not showing on UIViewController in xcode 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198661/why-storyboard-ui-elements-not-showing-on-uiviewcontroller-in-xcode-6)

[Storyboard UI Elements not displaying in editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26911207/storyboard-ui-elements-not-displaying-in-editor)

If we add new elements to it they are directly not visible. Also adding new ViewController to a "old" storyboard it does not show its content if we add elements to it.

What is going on here and how do i solve that?

Answer (score 3):

For example, we have **TopView** (my CustomView):

1. **TopView.xib**, set TopView class in **File's Owner**
   [image: TopView in Xcode]
2. **TopView.swift**

```
 

import UIKit
```

@IBDesignable
class TopView: UIView {

//MARK:- IB Outlets
var contentView:UIView?

//MARK:- Lifecycle
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupThisView()
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupThisView()
}

override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    setupThisView()
    contentView?.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
}

//MARK:- Lifecycle methods
private func setupThisView(){
    guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    addSubview(view)
    contentView = view
}

func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
    let nibName = String(describing: TopView.self)
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
    return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self,options: nil).first as? UIView
}
}

3.Add **UIView** in **Storyboard** and set the class of the view as **TopView**
[image: Custom class for UIView]

> If the **TopView** has **not** yet appeared in **Storyboard** then (this happens usually):

1. Enable **Editor -> Automatically Refresh Views**
2. Click on **Editor** -> **Refresh All Views**

> Still?

1. Clean the project: **⌘ + K**
2. Build the project **⌘ + B**

**Result in Storyboard:**
[image: Storyboard Result of TopView]

p.s I just copy this one from my answer here: [Custom view (xib) not visible on storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495016/custom-view-xib-not-visible-on-storyboard/49258792#49258792)

Answer (score -2):

**1.** Open the Xib/Storyboard

**2.** Select the file attributes tab (on the far left)

[image: file attributes tab]

**3.** click the "opens in" property and change it from Xcode 8 to Xcode 7

[image: opens in property]

Comment: I'd like to do that, but if i reopen that file it selects code 8.0 again. In addition to that, this answer does not explain why the old Storyboards/xib do work with Xcode 8 selected.